# C# Linq how to compare two strings and report the first different char which is itself different from '?' wildcard

Tags: c#, linq

I have a function which compares two strings and report the first different char:

```
public static int Diff(this string str1, string str2)
{
    try
    {
        if (str1 == null || str2 == null)
            return 0;
        int index = str1.Zip(str2, (c1, c2) => c1 == c2).TakeWhile(b => b).Count();
        return index;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

so all the magic is here:

```
int index = str1.Zip(str2, (c1, c2) => c1 == c2).TakeWhile(b => b).Count();
```

let's say that we have two strings:

> INPUT,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
>
> INPUT,?,?,1,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
>
> 01234567890

so considering all the chars the first different one is ? so the answer is 6 (starting from 0). That works properly.

Now I would like to introduce ? as a wildcard char which has therefore to be skipped and so the answer should be 10 (starting from 0).

I don't know how to change the code above in the linq expression in order to do that.
I tried `int index = str1.Zip(str2, (c1, c2) => c1 == c2 && c2!='?').TakeWhile(b => b).Count();` but that doesn't change a thing and always reports 6 instead of 9.

I would like to stick to linq instead of going through an (easier) for loop
Thanks

Comment: `c1 == c2 || c2 == '?'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the wildcard to count as an additional possible `true` condition.  Therefore you need to use OR `||` instead of AND `&&`:

Not:

`int index = str1.Zip(str2, (c1, c2) => c1 == c2 && c2 != '?').TakeWhile(b => b).Count();`

Instead:

`int index = str1.Zip(str2, (c1, c2) => c1 == c2 || c2 == '?').TakeWhile(b => b).Count();`

You can add an additional `||` to the expression if you also want to ignore wildcards in the first input.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to change the logical condition slightly.

If the condition used in the `Zip` is ever false, we stop looking there. We should stop looking only when the two characters are *not* the same *and* one of them is not a wildcard.

So the condition should be:

```
!(c1 != c2 && (c1 != '?' || c2 != '?'))
```

Obviously that could be simplified using DeMorgan's laws:

```
c1 == c2 || c1 != '?' || c2 != '?'
```

Therefore the line becomes:

```
index = str1.Zip(str2, (c1, c2) => c1 == c2 || c1 != '?' || c2 != '?').TakeWhile(b => b).Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

using linq, [Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LYlqOx).

```
var index = c1.Zip(c2, (a, b) => new { a, b })
            .Select((p, i) => new { p.a, p.b, i })
            .Where(p => p.b != wildcard)
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.a != p.b)?.i;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is full tested solution :

```
            string input1 = "1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0";
            string input2 = "\u003F,\u003F,1,\u003F,\u003F,\u003F,\u003F,\u003F,\u003F,\u003F,\u003F,\u003F";

            int results = input1.Select((x, i) => new { chr = x, index = i }).Where(x => (x.chr != input2[x.index]) && (x.chr != '\u003F') && (input2[x.index] != '\u003F')).Min(x => x.index);
```